# How do I detect only one touch when a hand is applied to the iPad screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am developing an iPad application for children with motor disabilities. The problem is that many of them try to interact with the application using their whole hand or their fist. In addition, their hands shake and they take too long to raise their entire hand from the screen.  This leads to the application registering multiple touch events when they interact with the screen.

How can my application only originate one event every time the child presses on a view?

Comment: Tough one.  I have "essential tremor" and have trouble with touch screens.  There are settings on the UI buttons to essentially disable the button when pressed once so that you have to reset it from the program.  I don't recall the details, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough one. But your question "What do you suggest so that only originate an event every time the child presses the view?" You can disable multiple touch.

You disable multitouch with the multipleTouchEnabled property. For example this would disable the view controller's view's multitouch.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
}
```

Another pointer is that iOS devices have the `VoiceOver` feature which is primarily for those with hearing disabilities, but might be helpful in this case. You can turn `VoiceOver` on in settings and check that out.

Assuming you are a registered apple developer they have some WWDC sessions on accessibility as well.

Hope this helps, always nice to see consideration for those with disabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than tracking each touch event individually, you can monitor all current touches and average their X and Y coordinates to produce a single value that would represent the centroid of these touches.  This one value could be used as your input to determine where on a view was touched, and process that interaction as desired.

Additionally, you might be able to use a low-pass filter on the touch locations to eliminate some of the jitter that might come from shaky hands.  You might also be able to use a slight delay after the liftoff of touches before that's really registered, in case someone's hand shakes enough to disconnect from the screen and reconnect soon afterward.

Even for users without motor disabilities, I've added little tweaks and heuristics with the touch events to account for the imprecision of human hands.  There isn't one easy solution, though, because a lot of experimentation is required for each case.